# Visual Studio Code - Focus on Interactive Window Upon Code Execution

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have my VS Code set up to create a new interactive window per file. This works fine. However, when I run code from my Python program using the shortcut shift + enter, it will not switch the tab to the interactive window that it executes the code in. Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Settings( Ctrl + , ) you can see the search bar. There, put in 'Send Selection To Interactive Window' or the like, and click the checkbox of 'Python › Data Science: Send Selection To Interactive Window'. After that, you would be able to run certain lines directly in the Interactive Window.

Hope this could help you. :)

Comment: Hi @mingjie, that is working fine. It is running my code in the interactive window, but it is not automatically switching over to the interactive window when it does that.

Comment: I think this hasn‘t been implemented yet. I will help you submit the relevant application on GitHub